# How can I work around the 2GB database limit of MS Access (for displaying images)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, database, frontend, digital-assets

**ORIGINAL QUESTION
 (How can I display images from a MySQL database in an Access 2007 form?)**

I would like to use Access 2007 to interface to a MySQL database and display pictures and other data in a form.

I already have an Access 2007 application that I don't want to change much, if I can help it. I'm just not sure what data type will work. ["Attachment Data Type"](http://aspalliance.com/1138_Working_with_Attachment_data_type_in_Microsoft_Access_2007.2) is not supported in MySQL. Also, my client wants to be able to open and edit the image.



**SOLUTION to UPDATED QUESTION

(How can I work around the 2GB database limit of MS Access (for displaying images)?)**

(1) Store the *filenames* of the images in MS Access
(2) Use VBA to dynamically display them in a form (see [How to display images from a folder in a form, a report, or a data access page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;285820)).

To make the images editable:
(1) Make sure the file type (e.g. ".jpg") is associated with the image editor of choice.
(2) Using the same variable names as in the [article mentioned above](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;285820), add the following code to the form in which `ImageFrame` is located (see [How to open a file in its default application using VBA](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32714181/how-to-open-a-file-in-its.aspx))

```
Private Sub ImageFrame_Click()
    Application.FollowHyperlink (txtImageName)
End Sub
```

**A few other sources that may be useful**

[Perl, MySQL, and Blobs](http://www.raditha.com/mysql/blob.php)

[VB, MySQL, and Blobs](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/vb-blob-handling.html)

[Using images in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA011472041033.aspx#AddImageTOOLE)

[Using MS Access as a front end to PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/24-Using-MS-Access-with-PostgreSQL.html).

*A special thanks to **MindStalker** for his comment that got me started on yet another round of "Googling".*

Comment: I've attached OLEDB to a MySQL blob and it worked just fine. Have you tried attaching "Attachment Data Type" to a MySQL blob?

Comment: Thanks! Still checking things out.

Comment: It seems that you found your own solution, and it gave me some ideas ... +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution mentioned in the question above.